# PWA behaviour in the background mode

Tags: google-chrome, progressive-web-apps

Our project includes a personal account, which works via chrome.

There is a special mechanism in Google Chrome to mitigate the negative effect on the background tabs (https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/03/background_tabs).

Nevertheless, for the purposes of our app, we need to disable this function for our app. Disabling via flags is not possible due to several reasons.

As far as we understand, we can solve this problem via PWA (Progressive Web Application). However, we cannot find any references of how PWA behaves in the background mode.

So please provide information - whether there are any restrictions on PWA in the background or the application is always "active"?

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what you're trying to do in the background?

Comment: I believe anything in the background mode loses location if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: We have a websocket connection, which receives various messages to change the state of the app: play sound, upload data from the backend and etc
Push notifications is not an option because of their unreliability and the time of their delivery. We definitely need to keep a websocket connection and get an instant response from the app during the message from this channel
Also the app with a certain periodicity communicates with the backend to check whether there are any new tasks for a user
@JoshLee